# Unable to start GNOME after hibernation

Tags: debian, hibernate

I'm using Debian 6 (Squeeze) and I happened to hibernate my laptop today. After hibernation everything was very slow (a lot of disk accesses... most likely page faults, I guess) but this is a usual behaviour in my case.

My usual fix to this situation is rebooting. However, this time I rebooted and GNOME never came back. GRUB is loaded and a lot of stuff is output to the console however at some point, when the console is replaced by a black screen in which GNOME will be loaded the black screen stays there.

I've been using `fglrx` driver for a year, however, I changed it in `xorg.conf` into `vesa`. This showed a little improvement as, although the situation repeated, instead of seeing a full black screen I could read:

```
lp: driver loaded but no devices found
ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

Those messages stayed on top of the screen blinking as if they were cleared and written in a loop. The fans went on so I guess there was some kind of loop doing something.

Hitting the power button shut down the laptop properly (the usual shutdown messages appeared in the screen).

I haven't seen any unusual output rather than that in `dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log` `/var/log/messages`.

Any ideas on what I can do? Maybe `dpgk-reconfigure` some packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a video driver issue. Reinstalling fglrx driver fixed this.